# Python conditional variable assignment

Tags: python, variables, conditional-statements, variable-assignment

Morning all,

Can someone advise, is it possible to achieve something like this:

```
def myFunction(someParam)
   if someParam == 1:
      return "This and that"
   else:
      return None

someVariable = someVariable || myFunction(valuePassedIn)
```

ie, given "someVariable" has an existing value, I want to preserve that value, or replace it with the value returned from "myFunction", provided that is not None?

Obviously, I can do something like:

```
if myFunction(valuePassedIn) != None:
    someVariable = myFunction(valuePassedIn)
```

But this of course is calling myFunction twice. Alternatively, I could do:

```
myFuncRes = myFunction(valuePassedIn)
if MyFuncRes != None:
    someVariable = myFuncRes
```

But it'd be good if I could reduce this to a single line of code, as per my "||" line in the first code snippet above. Obviously I've seen the [conditional expressions documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.5.html), but unless I'm misunderstanding, this would still involve calling `myFunction` twice?

I guess one other option would be to pass `someVariable` in as an additional param to `myFunction` and use this as the "else" return instead of None, but I can't help feeling this is kinda messy - and Python probably has something more slick I could use?

Thanks

Comment: Note that `if someParam = 1` in your `myFunction` is actually doing an assignment, not a comparison.

Comment: @Wieland it would be if it wasn't a `SyntaxError`

Comment: Sorry, typo on my part.... Edited ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can do this

Please check below code

```
>>> a = 1
>>> def test(b):
...     return b*10
...
>>> c = a or test(2)
>>> c
1
>>> a = 0
>>> c = a or test(2)
>>> c
20
```